# Why do I see edges partially see-through on back face (in viewport)?

Tags: 3d-view, geometry

Maybe you can help me with a weird viewport issue.

I want to show only visible edges in edit mode. i.e. I don't want to see those on the back side of the model. For some reason I always see partial edges in Solid Mode.

See the first image. There appears to be an 'inner cube' within my model. It occludes backface edges partially.

[image: Cube]

When I search on this topic people suggest toggling 'Limit Selection to Visible' in edit mode, and when I turn it on I can see all backface edges as expected, but the inner cube is still there.

It shows up in other models as well, like these steps:
[image: Steps]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34245/edit-mode-transparent-objects. Change clipping values for viewport in the *Toolshelf* panel.

Comment: Do you have a Solidify Modifier on that object? That would create an "inner cube". What are your Viewport Clipping settings? Does this still appear when using the default theme? These are questions I could already have the answer to if you had [posted your .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) along with the question. ;-)

Comment: no modifiers. Blender file: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1139" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1139/)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/49183/2843

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know the correct answer to this one, I think this is a limitation of the current opengl viewport rendering engine. Would like to hear from one of the devs about it, if it is actually fixable or a bug, or if anyone else knows any other way to fix it.

Only way to remedy the situation I found is to adjust viewport clipping. It's a workaround with its own side effects but can minimize the issue.

In the 3d view properties shelf <kbd>N</kbd> key, under the View panel there is a setting for viewpor clipping, star and end. Try bringing the two values closer together like increasing clip start and/or increasing clip end but keeping them in a usable state for your scene.

**Edit**: Worked well on my end
[image]

Ok, missed one detail, if you are in camera view mode, then you need to adjust the clipping settings in the camera's Object Data Settings in the Properties window, not viewport clipping as it has no effect while in camera view mode.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Changing the clipping seems to have no effect. http://s25.postimg.org/kui76ymct/Clipping.png

Comment: Worked well on my viewport, may be something related to your graphics card or drivers, check the original answer

Comment: hmm strange. Are you viewing through Camera or Perspective? I can reproduce this in perspective, but camera remains the same: http://s25.postimg.org/9jfjilfhr/Cube_Camera_v_Perspective_final.png

Comment: Of right didn't remember that, if you are in camera view mode you need to adjust the clipping settings in the camera's Object Data Settings in the Properties window, viewport clipping has no effect while in camera view mode.